# Nginx container returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, fpm

I have the following problem, I hope you can help me.

I have 3 docker containers, one with php-fpm, nginx and mysql.
When entering my website, the browser responds with a 502 Gateaway error code.
I am not understanding where I have the error. By the way, it is worth clarifying, the error varies between this error code but sometimes it also returns a 403 Forbiden.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
   app:
     build:
       context: .
     ports:
       - "9000:9000"
     volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html
     depends_on:
       -db
     environment:
       - TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
     networks:
       - stephvaez

   nginx:
       image: nginx:latest
       ports:
         - "9001:80"
         - "9002:443"
       volumes:
         - ./:/var/www/html
         - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
         - ./certificates:/etc/nginx/ssl
       depends_on:
         - app
       networks:
         - stephvaez

   DB:
     image: mysql:5.7
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: stephvaez
       MYSQL_DATABASE: stephvaez
     volumes:
       - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
     networks:
         - stephvaez

volumes:
   mysql-data: {}

networks:
   stephvaez:
```

Nginx configuration file:

```nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
        
    server_name storemanager.local;
        
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        
}
    
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/docker/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/docker/server.key;
    
    server_name storemanager.local;
    
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.html index.php;
    
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny there;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
    # Use a base image with PHP-FPM and Nginx
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install extensions necessary for Laravel and other dependencies
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Install Nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy your Nginx configuration
COPY ./nginx-conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Copy certificates
COPY certificates/ /etc/nginx/ssl/

# Configure Nginx to work with PHP-FPM
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server app:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

# Start both Nginx and PHP-FPM
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What does your app's `Dockerfile` look like?

Comment: I'll edit the question right away and add my Dockerfile, I'm sorry, I didn't realize it was necessary.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to run NGINX from your php-fpm image. Remove all the NGINX parts as well as the `CMD`. You've already got a separate service for NGINX

Comment: This means that once I delete everything you mentioned, should I run docker compose up -d --build again?

Comment: Yes. That should be all you need

Comment: Should I delete all of this?
# Install Nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
# Copy your Nginx configuration
COPY ./nginx-conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Copy certificates
COPY certificates/ /etc/nginx/ssl/

# Configure Nginx to work with PHP-FPM
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server app:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

# Start both Nginx and PHP-FPM
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Comment: You are all I need for my life for the rest of my days hahaha, I've been struggling with this for days, IT WORKED!!! Now, I have a question: How do you create Docker containers for the database, nginx, and php-fpm? What's the difference between my docker-compose file and the Dockerfile? It's not clear to me, does the PHP container get created based on the Dockerfile? And how are the other containers created? What about their dependencies?

Comment: `Dockerfile` is used to _build_ images. `docker compose up` runs images as _containers_. When you use `build` in a compose service, it builds the image based on the `Dockerfile`. Without `build`, it just runs the `image` as-is. So in your case, it builds `app`, then runs `app`, `nginx` and `DB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Docker Compose stack is set to use the `nginx` service as a front-end which proxies PHP requests through to the `app` service (php-fpm).

The `app` service should *only* be running php-fpm, not NGINX. By overriding the image's `CMD`, you're no longer running `php-fpm` which is why NGINX couldn't proxy requests through to it.

Remove all the NGINX specific parts from your `Dockerfile`...

```docker
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Install extensions necessary for Laravel and other dependencies
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

and rebuild your `app` service image

```sh
docker compose build app
```